# Execute PHP in background passing GET Params

Tags: php, linux, apache, get, cmd

I need to execute a heavy PHP script, in background,

I use this to execute some other PHP scripts

```
 exec("C:/AppServ/php5/php phptest.php> C:/AppServ/www/common/output.txt 2>&1 &");
```

But now I need to pass some GET parameters to these scripts, and obviously, catch them. How can I add my params?

Comment: `$_GET` only exists in HTTP context. You want to use command line parameters instead. Check out `$argc` and `$argv`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php

Comment: Thanks, anyway what I need was to can pass some params, I solved it using `exec("C:/AppServ/php5/php phptest.php $param1 $param2> C:/AppServ/www/common/output.txt 2>&1 &");` and receive it using `$argv[]` on my other script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get is a [CRUD function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), although CRUD isn't exclusive to the HTTP protocol it isn't the method used by the shell.

[Command line arguments in php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) is what you're looking for. They're not too dissimilar from put get parameters at the end of a url proceeding a question mark.